# Play again feature only working when user loses the game (hangman)

Tags: python

So after the user either wins or loses, they get asked if they want to play again (Y/N).

Here 3 things that are supposed to happen:

They type Y and they start a new game.

They type N and the game closes.

They type a different character, in which case they get the message: Please type a valid answer. (Y/N), and they get asked if they want to play again

When the user loses and they get asked to play again, all three of the criteria above work. *However*, when the user wins and is asked to play again, only the invalid character message works. When they type Y, they get put in a new game except the letters you have already guessed don't reset + after one guess, the word is revealed instantly and they 'win' again (you're 'guesses left' also don't reset). When they type N, then the game continues.

Here are images of the problems:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1Ftw.jpg

I have absolutely no clue of whats going on because I used the same code for each scenario (user wins or user loses):

```
        playagain = input('Wanna play again? (Y/N) ').upper()
        if playagain == 'Y':
            word = random.choice(wordbank)
        elif playagain == 'N':
            print('Alright, goodbye.')
        while playagain != 'Y' and playagain != 'N':
            print('Please type a valid answer. (Y/N)')
            print()
            playagain = input('Wanna play again? (Y/N) ').upper()
```

Here's my whole gamecode:

```
# importing wordbank
import random
from wordbankcool import wordbank

# hangman graphics
hangman_graphics = ['_',
                    '__',
                    '__\n |',
                    '__\n |\n O',
                    '__\n |\n O\n |',
                    '__\n |\n O\n/|',
                    '__\n |\n O\n/|\ ',
                    '__\n |\n O\n/|\ \n/',
                    '__\n |\n O\n/|\ \n/ \ '
                    ]

# code is inside while loop
playagain = 'Y'
while playagain == 'Y':

    # alphabet
    alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
                'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

    # basic functions of the game
    mistakes = 0
    letters_guessed = []
    mistakes_allowed = len(hangman_graphics)

    # selecting a random word for the user to guess
    word = random.choice(wordbank)

    # letters user has guessed stored in list, making each letter of the word seperate
    letters_word = list(word)
    wrong_letters = []

    print()

    # amount of letters the word has
    print(f'The word has {len(letters_word)} letters')

    # while loop which will run until the the number of mistakes = number of mistakes allowed
    while mistakes < mistakes_allowed:
        print()
        print('Incorrect guesses: ', end='')
        for letter in wrong_letters:
            print(f'{letter}, ', end='')
        print()
        print(f'Guesses left: {mistakes_allowed - mistakes}')
        letter_user = input('Guess a letter: ').lower()

    # checking if the letter has been guessed before
        while letter_user in letters_guessed or letter_user in wrong_letters:
            print()
            print('You have already guessed this letter. Please guess a different one.')
            letter_user = input('Guess a letter: ')

    # increasing amount of mistakes if the letter that has been guessed is not in the word + checking if guess is a letter
        if letter_user not in alphabet:
            print('Please only enter A LETTER.')
            continue
        if letter_user not in letters_word:
            mistakes += 1
            wrong_letters.append(letter_user)

        print()

        # showing how many letters the user has/has not guessed
        print('Word: ', end='')

    # if letter is in word, its added to letters guessed
        for letter in letters_word:
            if letter_user == letter:
                letters_guessed.append(letter_user)

    # replace letters that haven't been guessed with an underscore
        for letter in letters_word:
            if letter in letters_guessed:
                print(letter + ' ', end='')
            else:
                print('_ ', end='')

        print()

    # hangman graphics correlate with amount of mistakes made
        if mistakes:
            print(hangman_graphics[mistakes - 1])
        print()
        print('-------------------------------------------')  # seperator

    # ending: user wins
        if len(letters_guessed) == len(letters_word):
            print()
            print(f'You won! The word was {word}!')
            print()
            playagain = input('Wanna play again? (Y/N) ').upper()
            if playagain == 'Y':
                word = random.choice(wordbank)
            elif playagain == 'N':
                print('Alright, goodbye.')
            while playagain != 'Y' and playagain != 'N':
                print('Please type a valid answer. (Y/N)')
                print()
                playagain = input('Wanna play again? (Y/N) ').upper()

    # ending: user loses
    if mistakes == mistakes_allowed:
        print()
        print('Unlucky, better luck next time.')
        print()
        print(f'The word was {word}.')
        print()
        playagain = input('Wanna play again? (Y/N) ').upper()
        if playagain == 'Y':
            word = random.choice(wordbank)
        elif playagain == 'N':
            print('Alright, goodbye.')
        while playagain != 'Y' and playagain != 'N':
            print('Please type a valid answer. (Y/N)')
            print()
            playagain = input('Wanna play again? (Y/N) ').upper()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block that checks for the player winning is inside the while loop that has the condition `mistakes < mistakes_allowed`. Since that condition remains true and there is no `break` statement, it just continues to repeat from there rather than getting back out far enough to repeat the whole `playagain == 'Y'` loop. You either need to change that loop condition or add a `break` statement.